# antivirus popup while using c++

Tags: c++, access-denied

I am new to C++.I am following freeCodeCamp.org tutorial on C++.
The program looks like this-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int luckyNums[] = {4,8,15,16,23,42};
  cout << luckyNums[2];

  return 0;   
}
```

since I had VS code already installed I did not install code blocks.

Every time I run the above program I get an error "Access is denied". Also at the same time McAfee pops up saying "we just stopped a virus". I couldn't find a solution to this on Google anywhere.

When I was trying to do something with the code, in line 6 I did

```
cout << luckyNums[2] << endl;
```

and it worked and returned 15 but now the problem was I didn't understand why it worked because Mike got the result without doing this in code blocks.
Mike is the person giving the tutorial on freeCodeCamp.org

Comment: Exclude the folders you are compiling to from your virus scanner. Antivirus and development are not always friends (by definition at every build you change the content of an executable, and not all scanners like that)

Comment: Can you tell the antivirus to ignore project folder? Your little app is not a signed one and the antivirus does not trust it.

Comment: @nomoresegmentationfaults I don't think signing has anything to do with it. This even happened before signing was a thing :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer i am new to programming and i dont really know much. though i read somewhere to do the antivirus thing but i am not so sure about that. if I do what you say it wont infect my computer? also do i have an existing virus as the pop up says?

Comment: Well an AV is bound to check if the application is signed or not to check if publisher is trusted. It goes through multiple checks (if the app tries to use network or not etc.) and digital signature is one of those. @PepijnKramer

Comment: Exclude your develeopement folder from the virus scanner. Or get rid of the virus scanner alltogether. When developping, virus scanners usually cause more harm than good. Or maybe just ask Mike.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I turned off real time scanning and it worked